# If not enabled, do nothing (custom wishlist extension breaks template)

Tags: magento-1.8, wishlist

I have made a custom wishlist extension, based on Mage_Wishlist (it's a copy of Mage_wishlist).

In checkout/cart.phtml and /checkout/cart/item/default.phtml, this piece of code creates my own custom wishlist column:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('favorieten')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
            <col class="col-wish" width="1" />

        <?php endif ?>
```

It works perfectly when my custom extension is enabled, but it breaks the template when it's disabled.

How do I correctly add the column, so it doesn't break the template when the extension is turned off?

It is important to me so I can first add / replace the templates, and then finally activate the extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('[Namespace]_[Module]')) :  ?>
    <?php if ($this->helper('favorieten')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
        <col class="col-wish" width="1" />
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the piece of code of Marius didn't work, somehow it kept looking for the helper (which wasn't activated yet). I ended up with this, which is very similar, but worked.

```
<?php $moduleName = 'Namespace_Module'; ?>
<?php if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) : ?>
<?php if ($this->helper('favorieten')->isAllow()) : ?>
<col class="col-wish" width="1" />
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction Marius. I also got some info from this website: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-check-if-a-module-is-installed-enabled-or-active/